# How to put products from different content slots* in one carousel

Tags: salesforce, demandware

I faced with interesting situation.

When we need to put some products into carousel from content slot - we just open a selected template in this content slot (https://prnt.sc/rgcp9f) and get products from **slotcontent** `<isloop items="${slotcontent.content}...`.

But what we have to do when we need to show products from two different **content slots** in one carousel ?

The first content slot has **content type** *recommendation*
and second has **content type** *product*.

So which ways exist to combine these products from different templates in one carousel?

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

I think the best thing to do with this is to build a new rendering template that *just* outputs the product tiles. Assign that to both of the slot configurations. Then, you can wrap both `isslot` tags in the parent template with the container tags you need for the carousel.

I hope this helps,
Steve